# What does "come in" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The way in which simplicity **comes in** from supposing that there really
>   are physical objects is easily seen. If the cat appears at one moment
>   in one part of the room, and at another in another part, it is natural
>   to suppose that it has moved from the one to the other, passing over a
>   series of intermediate positions.

[Problems of philosophy - Bertrand Russell, Chapter II]

What does "**comes in**" in the text above mean?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this context, **come in** means the same thing it means in other contexts: **to enter**.

Because this is a philosophical text, usages can sometimes be a little strange or erudite.  Here Russell subtly anthropomorphizes "simplicity," talking about it like it was an active thing or even a person.

> Supposing that there are real physical objects allows simplicity to *come in* to or *enter* your mind (or perhaps to enter the situation or logical context).